# is there such layout options in android that take the rest space in parent container?

Tags: android-layout

I wanna do such a layout in android, i can't figure it out.

one button on top, one button at bottom, and a listview take the rest center area, how to make the listview take the rest area? is this possible if parent container is vertical LinearLayout?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i have done in my project is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/task_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/tasks" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/task_title" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/add_button">
        <!-- Preview: listitem=@layout/task_list_item -->
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:text="@string/no_tasks"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/task_title" 
        android:layout_above="@id/add_button"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/plus_sign" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/add_button"
        android:text="@string/remove_task" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With relative layout you can simply do it, the key layout properties are `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` , `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Comment: anyway no one will appreciate this kind of question in SO.